# Why doesn't my templated function promote 'int' to 'T', where 'T' = 'double'?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, type-promotion

I have a class templated with `typename T`. It contains a function,

```
template <typename T, size_t a>
myClass<T,a> operator+(myClass<T,a> lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return lhs += rhs;
}

myClass<T,a> myClass<T,a>::operator+=(const T& rhs) {
    // Do addition, depends on 'a'.
    return *this;
}
```

When I call this with, for example

```
myClass<double, 2> myObj_double_2(constructor args);
myObj_double_2 = myObj_double_2 + 5.2;
```

I have no problem.

If I however call

```
myObj_double_2 = myObj_double_2 + 5;
```

Then the compiler gives me a message like - `No match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'myClass<double, 2ul>' and 'int'). Candidates are ... note: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'const T' ('double' and 'int')`.

Can I write the code in some way to allow additional types to be passed that have a conversion to `T` (since, for example, double(5) is a valid constructor call)?

Comment: try `myObj_double_2 = myObj_double_2 + 5.0;`

Comment: Yes - this will work with no difficulties, but it doesn't solve the problem I was asking (although it is the simple and obvious solution)

Comment: No int->double "promotion" exists.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It sort of does.  For instance, declaring `void foo(double);` and then calling `foo(3)` is perfectly legal, as far as I can tell, and does the same thing as `foo((double)3)` or `foo(3.0)`.  So the issue here is more subtle.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Such an implicit conversion certainly exists, but that's not a "promotion", is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ah, so it's the distinction between "promotion" and "conversion" that's at issue here.  And this is probably what the OP was missing as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you are using template argument deduction, all deductions for one template parameter must have the *same* result.

In your case, the two deductions for `T` produce `double` and `int`, which are not the same, and so deduction fails.

What you can do is only use *one* function argument for template argument deduction, and make the other one *undeduced*:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t A>
void foo(myClass<T, A> arg1, typename std::common_type<T>::type arg2);
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that `std::common_type<T>::type` is essentially just `T`, but because the type of `arg2` is now a dependent type (its name appears to the right of a `::`), it is not deduced. Therefore, only the first argument takes part in deduction and produces `T = double` unambiguously, and then the second function parameter just has type `double`, and the usual conversions take place.

As a rule of thumb, template argument deduction does not cross `::`.

Comment: This is perfect, but I think you meant `typename std::common_type<T>::type`. Your solution also allows `const` and `&` to be added, which is great

Comment: @chrisb2244: Thanks, fixed. I leave the reference modifications to you; they're not material to the problem.

Comment: `common_type` decays the type; probably not relevant here, but is something to keep in mind.

Comment: @T.C.: Yes, that's why I said "essentially". There isn't a true `id<T>` template in the standard library, though it'd be trivial to write one should it be needed.

Comment: It would also be possible to add a typedef for `T` (i.e. `value_type`) inside `myClass` and use `template <typename T1, size_t a> myClass<T1,a> operator+(myClass<T1,a> lhs, typename myClass<T1,a>::value_type const & rhs);`

Comment: @chrisb2244: You can also pass the type through some external trait helper like Boost.Calltraits to let you outsource the policy of pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference to a separate trait. From your other comment I guessed that you might be interested in that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: True. We probably should have a `std::nondeduced<T>::type`, not because it's better than `std::common_type<T>::type`, but because it makes the intent obvious.

Comment: @MSalters: `std::kill_deduceacity_t<T>` :-)

Answer (score 17):

The compiler on overload resolution fails to find a right candidate for `operator+` because `T` is already being deducted to `double` and literal `5` is an integer. Solution:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, size_t a>
myClass<T1,a> operator+(myClass<T1,a> lhs, const T2& rhs) {
    return lhs += T1(rhs);
}
```

Comment: In the case where `T1` and `T2` are equal, this will presumably result in an unnecessary copy - will taking the parameter by value allow a move (and would it be likely to be any faster in the case of `int` and `double`?)

Comment: @chrisb2244 you could partially specialise for the case `T1 == T2`

Comment: Constructor-style casts are dangerous, if you want to only allow implicit conversions, then initialize a local of type `T1`.

Answer (score 9):

You are running into problems with template type deduction.

Both arguments are given "equal standing" when deducing the value of `T`, and in this case the two arguments disagree -- one says `T` should be `int`, the other says `T` should be `double`.

The right way to fix this is with Koenig operators.

Make `+=` and `+` and the like `friend`s of your class and implement inline:

```
template<class T, size_t a>
class myClass {
  // etc
public:
  friend myClass operator+(myClass lhs, const T& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return std::move(lhs);
  }
  friend myClass& operator+=(myClass& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    // do addition, depends on `a`
    return *this;
  }
};
```

this technique does something strange.  It creates non-`template` operators based on the template type of the class.  These are then found via ADL (Koenig lookup) when you invoke `+` or `+=`.

You get one of these operators per template instantiation, but they aren't template operators, so `const T&` isn't deduced, and conversion happens as expected.