# Cannot add integer to std::complex<double>

Tags: c++

I am trying to add integer to `complex<double>` but I cannot. Here is relevant part of code:

```
    using dcomplex = std::complex<double>;

    dcomplex j = dcomplex(0,1);
 // dcomplex r  = 1+j;//this line is not compiling
    dcomplex r  = 1.0+j;//ok
```

I understand why `j+=1` is not compiling, because `operator+=` overloaded inside `complex` and there are no implicit conversion `int->double`. However `operator+` is not overloaded inside complex(I did not find it there). So it is overloaded somewhere else(where? I cannot find it) and because of that `int` should be converted to `double` implicitly. But it is not. Why?

Comment: _"there are no implicit conversion int->double"_ Are you sure?

Comment: [Strangely related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32944584/560648)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) the overloads for [`std::complex::operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3) are

```
template< class T >
complex<T> operator+( const complex<T>& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);

template< class T >
complex<T> operator+( const complex<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);

template< class T >
complex<T> operator+( const T& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
```

When type deduction happens there is a conflict as it evaluates `T` to a `double` and an `int`.  Since `T` cannot be both it generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a non-member function, because the scalar is on the left. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3).  You can cast the integer to double or `j.value_type`.